# Jquery remove duplicate code

Tags: jquery

Am new to Jquery.

I want to insert and edit values on the same button click.The following code is am using .It is working properly and using common code in both insertion and deletion.

```
function save(){

if($('#job').val()==" "){
    if(value!=false){
    var data = {        
        "names": $('#names').val(),            
        "server": $('#server').val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: "/insert",
               });
  }
}
else{

    if(value!=false){
    var data = {

    };
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: "/edis",
                   }
    });
  }
}
}
```

Is there any possible ways to remove code duplication and how to compress this code

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Put the URL and success log messages in variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED**

```
function saveToDB(){
var value= pageValidation();
var job;
var msg;

if(value!=false){

var data = {
        "jobid": $('#jobid').val(),
        "names": $('#names').val(),
        "os": $('#OS').val(),
        "browser": $('#browsers').val(),
        "version": $('#version').val(),
        "scripttype": $('#testscripts').val(),
        "server": $('#server').val()
    };

if($('#jobid').val().trim() == ""){
    job = "/insertJobs";
    msg = "job insertion success";
    delete data['jobid'];
}
else{
    job = "/editJobs";
    msg = "job Updated succesfully!!";
}



    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: job,
        dataType: "json",
        data: data,
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(msg);
            console.log(response);
            displayjobs();
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: for newJob there is not `jobId`, whereas for edit it has `jobId`

Answer (score 1):

```
function saveToDB() {
    var value= pageValidation();
    var type = "update";
    if ($('#jobid').val()==" ") {   //set the flag
        type = "insert"
    }
    if(value!=false) {
        var data = {        
            "type": type, //See this, insert/update, check this on server side
            "names": $('#names').val(),
            "os": $('#OS').val(),
            "browser": $('#browsers').val(),
            "version": $('#version').val(),
            "scripttype": $('#testscripts').val(),
            "server": $('#server').val()
        };
        if (type == "update") {
            data.jobid = $('#jobid').val();
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: "/insertJobs",
            dataType: "json",
            data: data,
            success: function (response) {
                if (type == "insert") {
                    console.log("job insertion success");
                } else {
                    console.log("job Updated succesfully!!");
                }
                console.log(response);
                displayjobs();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: while updating ` var data` contains `id` field

Comment: almost.... your data doesn't match. set a default data then add elements depending of insert/update

Answer (score 1):

In your main condition you duplicate almost the same code. You can convert this code into function and cover small differences with function parameters. Calling this function in main condition should do the trick here.

Here is my customization (I didn't try the code):

```
function saveToDB(){
  var value = pageValidation();

  if($('#jobid').val()==" ") manageData('/InsertJobs'); else manageData('/editJobs', true);

}

function manageData(url, value = false){
  var data = {
      "jobid": $('#jobid').val(),        
      "names": $('#names').val(),
      "os": $('#OS').val(),
      "browser": $('#browsers').val(),
      "version": $('#version').val(),
      "scripttype": $('#testscripts').val(),
      "server": $('#server').val()
  };
  $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: url,
      dataType: "json",
      data: data,
      success: function (response) {
          if($value == false) console.log("job insertion success"); else console.log("job Updated succesfully!!");
          console.log(response);          
          displayjobs();
      }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Extend the **scope of variables**  within `saveToDB` method.

```
var data = {        
        "names": $('#names').val(),
        "os": $('#OS').val(),
        "browser": $('#browsers').val(),
        "version": $('#version').val(),
        "scripttype": $('#testscripts').val(),
        "server": $('#server').val()
    };
var urlLink;
var message;
```

2) From your code it seems, **`value`** variable is playing the vital role, there make it as first condition.

3) while assingning data object will not have `job` so here in this condition you can add it.

```
if($('#jobid').val()==" "){
 urlLink = "/insertJobs";
 message = "job insertion success";
}
else {
 data.job = $('#jobid').val();  // Add job to data object
 urlLink = "/editJobs";
 message = "job Updated succesfully!!";
}
```

Finally your code will be like

```
function saveToDB(){
    var value= pageValidation();
    if(value!=false){
        var data = {        
                "names": $('#names').val(),
                "os": $('#OS').val(),
                "browser": $('#browsers').val(),
                "version": $('#version').val(),
                "scripttype": $('#testscripts').val(),
                "server": $('#server').val()
            };  
        if($('#jobid').val()==" "){
         urlLink = "/insertJobs";
         message = "job insertion success";
        }
        else {
         data.job = $('#jobid').val();
         urlLink = "/editJobs";
         message = "job Updated succesfully!!";
        }           
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: urlLink,
            dataType: "json",
            data: data,
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(message);
                console.log(response);
                displayjobs();
            }
        });
      }
}
```